# Unexpected values counting characters in strings C#

Tags: c#, string

Trying to analyze the number of characters in file names vs file paths.

Given that `allfiles`are ALL the files in a directory, I am getting some unexpected results.  In one case, `file.Length.ToString()` = 281 while `fileName.Length.ToString()` = 288.  How could it be the file name contains more characters than the full path?

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"directory", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string file in allfiles)
            {
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
                string line = file.Replace(',', '?') + "," + file.Length.ToString() + "," + fileName.Length.ToString()+","+fileName;
                output.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just output the filename and the full path for that file and then you can see what the difference is?

Comment: Is this a quiz? You already wrote both file and fileName to your Output.txt, so why don't you show us the corresponding line in Output.txt?

Comment: I guess it is a file name with a rather long extension. `GetFileName(file)+ GetExtension(file)` will have the extension twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be more in line with what you are trying to do:

```
   foreach (string file in allfiles)
   {
       string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
       string line = file.Replace(',', '?') + ", " + file.Length.ToString() + ", " + fileName.Length.ToString() + "," + fileName;
       output.WriteLine(line);
   }
```

Adding an extra extension was throwing off your count.

Change

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
```

to

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
```